# What is the opposite of a cross term?

Tags: terminology

When we multiply out $(x + y)(x + y)$, we refer to the two $xy$ terms as "cross terms". Is there a corresponding term for the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms?

Comment: I'm not aware of standard terminology, but I'd call them "pure terms".

Comment: The happy terms?!

Comment: The "non-cross" terms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depending on the context, "diagonal terms" might work:

$$(x+y)(x+y)=\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{x\\y}\;;$$

the cross-terms are the off-diagonal terms in this quadratic form and the other ones are the diagonal terms.

Comment: +1, Came here to give this answer.  I think I have seen diagonal used most often.

Answer (score 3):

**Direct** or **straight** might be what you are looking for, as opposed to ***cross***, ***crossed*** or ***mixed*** (since each resultant term has either one variable to a power or two different variables, a "mixture").

I was also taught that you can multiply $(a+b)(c+d)$ using the acronym FOIL for First, Inside, Outside, Last (which is mixing sequential and spatial metaphors).

Answer (score 2):

The univariate terms is unambiguous. I like 'pure' but am not sure how correct this is.

Answer (score 1):

The squares or more general, the $n$th power.

Answer (score 1):

The aligned terms.             ............

Answer (score 1):

The square term or quadrature term is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Cord/chord is the term

Aligned would be the close next term as @John Bentin said. But lines or straight both can apply to cross.

Comment: I am curious why cord (or chord) is a good word choice here. I looked at these definitions, but did not make any useful connection: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chord

Comment: Cord is close to align as in Verb 2 of 2 in the link here, which where I would start then move onto noun form: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/chord

Comment: “He was being cordial” vs “He was being cross”